# ESCI, Impact Factor and its consequences

Tags: journals, bibliometrics

Starting from the 2023 JCR release, Journal Impact Factors were expanded to all Web of Science Core Collection journals including arts and humanities.

https://clarivate.com/blog/clarivate-announces-changes-to-the-2023-journal-citation-reports-release/

What are the consequences of this phenomenon? Will this inflate the IF even further or is it a good thing?

Comment: I suspect the answer will depend on one's feelings about impact factors in the first place.

Comment: Why (or how) would this inflate IF? What impact this has depends on your field I think.

Comment: @sErISaNo Why do you think it is field-dependent? Inflation is not limited to augmentation but could also indicate a negative inflation. That is why the question was asked in an open-end style.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you mean by inflate or augment, but I'm terms of general impact, I'd imagine the appearance of IFs in fields that previously did not use them would have a larger impact that whatever change would occur in a field that was already using the metric.